# finding set of tree decompositions to cover all pairs of vertices

Tags: statistical-physics, computational-complexity, graph-theory, graph-colorings

I first [asked this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2773/ensemble-of-tree-decompositions-for-all-pairs-problem) on cstheory.SE but got no reply.

Let $P(X_i=x)$ represent probability that randomly chosen [proper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) $q$-coloring of an $L\times L$ [square grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph#Square_grid_graph) contains color $x$ at position $i$. How do you efficiently compute $P(X_{i}=X_{j})$ for every pair $(i,j)$?

Fastest known [method](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4847) for counting $q$-proper colorings on grids uses tree decomposition. To extend it to this problem, one needs a set of tree decompositions so that every pair of vertices is contained in some bag. Is anything known about this problem?

Motivation: this is essentially two-point correlation function of Potts model, but also correlation function of self-avoiding walks and few other "all-pairs" problems face the same issue